# Unable to connect to ec2 windows instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed mysql 5.5 and tomcat 6 on an amazon ec2 windows micro instance. I am unable to access the pages deployed in tomcat from my local browser.It says The server at ec2-50-19-6-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond. 
When i pinged using my command prompt, it says request time out. 
Can somebody please help me??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your security settings and make sure that the ports are open for inbound requests.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have Http, mysql and rdp ports open. Please help

Comment: Remote into the box and try accessing it from the local host to make sure that it is up and running.  Then trail the logs while attempting to connect from your own machine.

Comment: Im able to access it from within the instance. I'll checkout the logs. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the windows firewall on the server. I changed the inbound rules.

Comment: sopt on, I was banging my head against the wall fo rlast couple of hours :)